# Elements is not displaying while positioning it outside the bottom modal in materializecss

Tags: css, materialize

I have a modal bottom of materializecss above which i want to display a title but when positioning it with absolute its getting hidden, i have tried few ways but unable to understand why this is happening.

Attached an image below for better understanding
[image]

As you can see the **hello** is getting hidden while i am trying to display it above the modal.

This is the CSS i have written for it

```
.title{
  padding:10px 15px;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
    position:inherit;
    bottom:320px;
    z-index:1100 !important;
}
```

Comment: Try `position:relative;` instead of `position:inherit;` and increase `z-index` too.

Comment: If i do relative, it's not displaying at all. it is going to the top, element is there but its hidden. i increased the z-index too. The element is inside the modal div @RohitVerma